# If $G$ is a finite group with normal subgroup $H$, and if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, then $G = N_G(P)H$

Tags: group-theory, solution-verification, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, sylow-theory

If $G$ is a finite group with normal subgroup $H$, and if $P$ is a Sylow $p$-subgroup of $H$, then

$$G = N_{G}(P)H.$$

---

Let $P\in{\rm Syl}_p(H)$, then the group $gPg^{-1}$ has the same order as $P$, thus it's in ${\rm Syl}_p(H)$, from the second Sylow theorem, there exists an element $h\in H$ s.t

$$hgPg^{-1}h^{-1}=P$$

and we get that $gh\in N_G(P)$ (because $gh\in G$). Now I can write $g=ghh^{-1}$, because $gh\in N_G(P)$ and $h^{-1}\in H$ and $g$ was arbitrary, $G = N_{G}(P)H$.

Is this correct? It seems a bit wrong since for every group we can write $g=ghh^{-1}$.

Comment: You have that $hg\in N_G(P)$, not $gh$. But it does not matter.

Comment: @markvs correct, I forgot to write it the same because $H$ is normal.

Comment: @Shaun probably it does, I didn't read it rigorous, but I think mine is a lot simpler and quicker.